# GroovyC error in IntelliJ

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea

I am getting below error due to some change in setting and I get this error while running test cases.

I have put all the jar files which is required for the same.

```
Groovyc: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/tools/javac/JavaAwareCompilationUnit
at org.jetbrains.groovy.compiler.rt.GroovycRunner.main(GroovycRunner.java:85)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:121)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.tools.javac.JavaAwareCompilationUnit
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
... 6 more
```

I have checked out two projects from SVN in two different locations in my system. I do not see any error for one project but for the other project I do while running test cases.

Comment: Which Groovy version are you using?

Comment: Its no matter of version because i imported two projects for one it is giving error and for other it is not

Comment: It seems like some of the Groovy core classes is missing in the jars so the version might be very important. Are they really the same in the two imported projects?

Comment: Yes they are same in both project as the both project are same but checked out twice from svn repository at two different locations in my hard disk.

Comment: Is there any chance you could provide a project demonstrating this issue, together with Groovy jars used by it?